# Multiselect Picklist with field dependencies

Tags: apex, visualforce, multi-select, dependent-picklist

I have an object, for example Student. In the Student object I have a multiselect picklist, that multiselect picklist having all country names. I have another picklist in the Student object having all state names. Here, the second multiselect picklist is dependent upon the first multiselect picklist.

My question is

1. How can I get country and state multiselect picklists into a Visualforce page?
2. Suppose I add new countries or states to the multiselect picklists; how are such values dynamically added to to the visualforce page?
3. How do I make the second multiselect picklist dependent upon the first one?

   For example if I select country name for that country, the appropriate states should display in the second picklist.

   1. How can I save these values into the object?

Comment: Have you tried <apex:outputfield> ? Maybe eplaining your use case a bit better will help

Comment: Are you sure you need a multiselect picklist? How would the dependency work? What should happen if the user selects multiple countries?

Comment: @metadaddy  Actually my business logic is different which i was post for understand purpose i post my question by using sample example.As per our logic we have give the option to user to select multiple values from multipicklist.

Comment: metadaddy pls suggest if u know the answer for this question